# What does this circuit do? (flip flop)

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, flipflop, sequential-logic

I am trying to understand a circuit which does two arithmetic operations of 5-bit words in 2 cycles:

- Q = 2*Q - A (one cycle)
- Q = 11*Q (two cycles)

What does this part do?

[image]

This is the whole circuit:

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and upload the images to the site using the "Image" button in the editor.

Comment: If you didn't draw the circuits yourself please link to where you found them on the internet. If you didn't find them on the internet, state where you came across them.

Comment: @Andy aka the first is mine the second is a solution from an exercise of a student (It is not on the internet) but if you wnat I could delete the second photo

Comment: Do you have any thoughts? What will happen to the \$\overline{Q}\$ value if `D` is held constant `0`? Constant `1`? Switching from `1` to `0` and vice versa?

Comment: Neither pictures are in any way complete enough to determine what they do without significant guesswork. Maybe you know what they do based on acquired knowledge but, that acquired knowledge isn't available to anyone looking at this question unless you spill the beans.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I think If D is held "0"  the Q will be  so the Q bar will be "1" ,  If D is held "1"  the Q will be "1"  so the Q bar will be "0"

Comment: So what will happen each clock if \$\overline{Q}\$ is connected to `D`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. This the part I could not clarify
I think that if Q bar is connected to D will be the input so if Q bar  is "0" the Q will be "0"
if Q bar is "1" the Q will be 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A D flip-flop sets its output \$Q\$ equal to its input \$D\$ on a clock edge. \$\overline{Q}\$ is the logical negation of \$Q\$. So essentially this is an one-bit counter- \$\overline{Q}\$ switches between 0 and 1 on every clock cycle.

Comment: So the only reason which I need this is  to switch the select value of multiplexer on every rise of the clock?

Comment: I would not call it an oscillator. An oscillator's output is a periodic function of time with no input whatsoever. A better name for OP's circuit might be "toggle." Another way to describe it would be "one bit counter."

Comment: @SolomonSlow Well oscillators can certainly have inputs (example: voltage-controlled oscillators), but I see your point. "Clock divider" would be another valid description.

Comment: @Bill97 Yes, from the looks of it that's all it's attached to.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, yes, an oscillator generates a steady frequency, so this isn't one. Oscillators can have control inputs, as a VCO has, but not a frequency source input - the oscillator is the source.